# Does column count matter if I need to request all the data from that 1 row?

Tags: sql, database

**TL;DR:** If you have 30 different values all pointing to same object id and you need to retrieve them all, does it make any difference if this data is in separate rows or all in same row (many columns)?

---

**Little context:**

WordPress has this very funny database setup (*IMO*):

- Posts have their own table and all the essential data is in vertical "layout" (like 1st code block)
- All other related data you might want to add to post has separate table and it's like in 2nd code

I think I understand what they are doing - bloggers or theme builders wouldn't want to mess with DBs.

---

This is my first from start-to-finish project and Im not an expert in databases. So I figured it's best to take example from my old friend WordPress. I use Node.js server, GraphQL and MariaDB database.

Project requires a lot of data per post (individual, can't normalize) and I will eventually have a situation where I have like 200 000 rows in post table and 30 times as much in other, this raises a question:

Why just not to put all 30 values to columns instead of rows?

I've watched few hours of technical tutorials and read blogs but Im still not 100% sure how it works under the hood: **If I need all the data below in one request, which "design" should I choose?** Is WordPress wrong & they just have to do this for user convenience (2nd has lots of repeating keys)?

I don't much care about storage, I care about super fast reads and also kind of fast writes.

---

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 id |  post id  |  color  |  shape  |  weight  |  length  |  width
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 1       55        blue      sqare      50        110        110
```

---

```
-------------------------------------
 id |  post_id   |  key  |   value  
-------------------------------------
 1       55        color      blue
 2       55        shape      sqare
 3       55        weight     50
 4       55        length     110
 5       55        width      110
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress did that to promote less database changes as their product evolves. Imagine this situation: If they have to create a new column to correspond to a new attribute, how difficult would be for users, at every change, promote the needed database changes.
And in fact, most dynamic databases, used in CMS like Wordpress have this concept to allow for easy changes. Other types of systems also does that.

Comment: I understand and Im not trying to attack someone or something. But my question was: which route should I choose? Is WP approach a disservice for queries' speed?

Comment: You should choose the approach that will suit your objectives better. I mean, if you foresee that your solution will not grow in terms of new attributes in the future, use columns. Now, if you see the complexity grows overtime, maybe a dynamic attribute table will be a best approach.

Comment: So to give the OP an advice for his situation, make the database specific since you have complete control and put all related fields in one row.

Comment: One extra information: the performance will not be harmed if your database is well tunned. Also, if you want to decrease the complexity of the queries, you use views to hide the underlying complexity or even create a more denormalized database for reporting specifics, for example.